# Lost in creating multiple meta boxes

Tags: themes, metabox

I've been working for days to get this working without luck. Hope someone can help me.

I created multiple metaboxes but my backend shows the boxes empty, I am lost and don't know where to go with this.
Note that I am not closed to use multiple metaboxes as long as I can divide in blocks the info but I'm a noob...

so any help is accepted. Please be patient because I need a detailed explanation.

My code is:

```
$prefix = 'ikos_';
$metaboxWrapper = array();

$metaboxWrapper[] =
$meta_box = array(
'id' => 'features',
'title' => 'Property Features',
'page' => 'post',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Price (in USD)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

      array(
        'name' => 'Price (in Mexican Peso)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Address',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'textarea',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'std' => ''
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Property for',
        'id' => $prefix . 'select',
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array('Sale', 'Rent', 'Vacational Rental')
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Area (m2)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Area of terrain (m2)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

   array(
        'name' => 'Number of rooms',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Number of bathrooms. Include half bathrooms (ex. 2 1/2)',
        'desc' => '',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ' '
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Service Bathroom',
        'id' => $prefix . 'checkbox',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'Furnished',
        'id' => $prefix . 'checkbox',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
    )
));
```

Then I have more metaboxes with checkbox groups like this:

```
$metaboxWrapper[] =
$meta_box = array(  
'id' => 'installed',
'title' => 'Installed',
'page' => 'post',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'label' => 'Installed',  
'desc'  => '',  
'type'  => 'checkbox_group', 
        'fields' => array(  
'options' => array(  
    'one' => array(  
        'label' => 'Air conditioner',  
        'value' => 'one'  
    ),  
    'two' => array(  
        'label' => 'Stationary gas',  
        'value' => 'two'  
    ),  
    'three' => array(  
        'label' => 'Water heater',  
        'value' => 'three'  
    ), 

    'four' => array(  
        'label' => 'Hurricain shutters or hurricain protection',  
        'value' => 'four'  
    ),

    'five' => array(  
        'label' => 'Telephone line',  
        'value' => 'five'  
    )
)  
));
```

And to show them I have this but doesn't work. I can't even go to the part of saving and showing data in front end...so I don't know if it works. Still I pase it here so you can point me if I am doing it wrong.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box');

// Add meta box
function mytheme_add_box() {
global $metaboxWrapper;

foreach($metaboxWrapper as $meta_box)
{
add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'mytheme_show_box', $meta_box['page'],  $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}
}


// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function mytheme_show_box() {
global $meta_box , $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="',    wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';
echo '<div class="form-table">';
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
    // get current post meta data
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
    echo '<tr>',
            '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
            '<td>';
    switch ($field['type']) {
        case 'text':
            echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
        case 'textarea':
            echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
        case 'select':
            echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                echo '<option ', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            break;
        case 'radio':
            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
            }
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
            break;


// checkbox_group  
case 'checkbox_group':  
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {  
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$option['value'].'" name="'.$field['id'].'[]" id="'.$option['value'].'"',$meta && in_array($option['value'], $meta) ? ' checked="checked"' : '',' />  
            <label for="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</label><br />';  
}  
echo '<span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
break;    

    }
    echo     '</td><td>',
        '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}

do_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');
// Save data from meta box
function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {
global $metaboxWrapper;
// verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    return $post_id;
}
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post_id;
}
// check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }
} elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
    return $post_id;
}
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
    $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
    if ($new && $new != $old) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
    } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
    }
}
}

// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
return $post_id;
}
```

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? You mention "front end" several times. Are you trying to show the meta boxes on the front end of the site?

Comment: oh snap! you are right, I meant backend the first time I wrote it. The post is edited tho.. About debugging...I get this:   Undefined index: id in /home/homesmore/homes-more.com.mx/wp-content/themes/ElegantEstate/metabox.php on line 329

Notice: Undefined index: name in /home/homesmore/homes-more.com.mx/wp-content/themes/ElegantEstate/metabox.php on line 331

Notice: Undefined index: type in /home/homesmore/homes-more.com.mx/wp-content/themes/ElegantEstate/metabox.php on line 333

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91406/21376 for the undefined index issues. You should fix those but I don't think that will fix your problem.

Comment: I see that the lines that have errors are a lot of lines, the ones that have $field in it..

Comment: Now I get this error: Undefined variable: meta_box in /home/homesmore/homes-more.com.mx/wp-content/themes/ElegantEstate/metabox.php on line 324 But I am lost :(

Comment: One way to narrow down a problem is to remove the bulk of it, I suggest you strip out everything except one simple array and try to output it where you want, since it looks like you have some PHP issues. It aslo makes it easier for people to look it over to answer.

Comment: I'd like to strip it out but still want show two metaboxes with different arrays (text field, checkboxes and checkbox group) At first I made just one meta box with all inside but It was not separated and I didnt know how to divide the data fields by adding html tags or something... Will it be easier to use just one metabox?

Comment: Hey, I think I solved the undefined index but now I get this errors: Notice: Undefined variable: meta_box in /home/homesmore/homes-more.com.mx/wp-content/themes/ElegantEstate/metabox.php on line 324

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/homesmore/homes-more.com.mx/wp-content/themes/ElegantEstate/metabox.php on line 324 and this is the line     `foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {` can you please point me in the right direction @s_ha_dum?

Comment: "Undefined variable" is essentially the same error and the fix is the about the same.